# Image php5.6-apache. debbuging my code

Tags: apache, docker, php-5.6

I'm using docker-compose to create two containers connected between them. (the images are php5.6-apache and mysql).

Everything is running OK. my problem is when i want to start working. i cant see the typical errors in php. (i always worked on xampp). i've seen a lot of documentation how to enable the debugs but i cant find a solution. I tried to find php.ini but apparently it is not in the apache container. I tried to install xdebug as the documentation...
anyone know how to do it?

I need to do it in php 5.6 as my application doesn't work with newer versions.

Comment: Check this other thread.  It will give you ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272178/from-where-is-my-php-ini-being-loaded/47272568?noredirect=1#comment81542982_47272568.  Run phpinfo to know where php.ini should be, then you have to create one, anyway read up.

Comment: thanks Nic3500. i tried what they say but nothing. i wrote in the post. Let's see if there is a way.

Cheers

Comment: Running phpinfo() should show you the list of parameters for the PHP running in the docker.  Among these you will see the directory where it expects the php.ini file to be.  You will then have to copy the file php-development.ini (or php-production.ini) from the install directory to the phpinfo() listed directory.

Comment: yes. it says:

Virtual Directory Support  disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File  /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d 

and i have in "/usr/local/etc/php" my php.ini. with
display_errors=On    and     display_startup_errors=On

but i still cannot see the errors. any idea?